# Android Deep linking

Tags: android, html, web, deep-linking

I am trying to add deep linking on Android , so in my web page i replace an iframe like this

```
<iframe  scrolling="no" width="1" height="1" style="display: none;" 
src="myscheme://post/5002"></iframe>
```

and in my manifest.xml (android app)

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

but when i open the webpage in chrome it didn't show the "open with" dialog to choose my app

i tested the deeplinking for android using this and the dialog appears

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW  -d "myscheme://whatever"
```

Comment: What version of Android are you testing with?

Answer (score 2):

The functionality has changed slightly in Chrome for Android, versions 25 and later. It is no longer possible to launch an Android app by setting an iframe's src attribute. you should use the “intent:” syntax instead

intent://host/#Intent;scheme=protocol;package=com.domain.apppackage;end

The basic syntax for an intent-based URI is as follows:

> intent:
>     HOST/URI-path // Optional host 
>      #Intent; 
>         package=[string]; 
>         action=[string]; 
>         category=[string]; 
>         component=[string]; 
>         scheme=[string]; 
>      end;

please check this [page](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)

Answer (score 1):

The iframe solution is not valid anymore with the latest versions of Chrome. As Anas said you need to create a link with an "intent://..:" address. Also the user needs to do some action to open the link.

To solve this problem I've created a link shortener tool. You can use it here:
http://www.uppurl.com/

This tool takes care of creating the appropriate deep links based on the user browser. I recommend you to use it as it solve a lot of work for you and you don't even need to modify or have a server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try to use JavaScript instead of iframe:

```
location.href = "myscheme://post/5002"
```

Also, just to test whether it's working or not at all, you can try to set host and path on your data element in intent-filter:

```
<data android:scheme="myscheme"
                  android:host="post"
                  android:pathPrefix="502">
```